# Webpack add query string to bundle for cache-busting

Tags: caching, webpack

so in my index.html, I have this line to include the webpack bundle

```html
<script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

And my webpack config looks like this:

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/main.js",
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
    hotOnly: true
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
};
```

How could I modify this, to add a query string (?v=some_nr) to the bundle when I run `webpack --mode production`. I can copy the index.html to dist/index.html or some other location, if needed, I'll be moving it to the webroot automatically anyway afterwards.

Comment: It does not look like Webpack manages your `index.html`, and I guess you have some other automation to copy it, right? In this case, you could append `?v=UUID` to `index.html` when copying to `dist`, it does not actually matter where this UUID comes from. (could be commit hash for example)